# Grouping values in a dataframe based on file origin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes: data1 and data2. I use the concat function to join the 2 datasets

```
dataset = pd.concat([data1, data2], ignore_index=True)
```

Is there a way i can group the data thats in my new dataframe (dataset) to show which which values came from data1 and which values came from data2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you can use this very simple approach:

```
data1['file_origin'] = 'data1'
data2['file_origin'] = 'data2'
dataset = pd.concat([data1, data2], ignore_index=True)
```